# Why does this suds script return urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known?

Tags: python, suds

Still quite new to Python. I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371052/python-suds-urlerror-name-or-service-not-known-issue). My script is attempting to connect with a web-service that uses wsse on messages and is provisioned using HTTPS. I have to use a non-authenticated proxy. I use suds to use the service as follows:

```
import logging
import suds
import urllib2
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated

#---These are not real values but represent them.---------
SERVICE_URL = 'https://service.com/1/soap'
SERVICE_USR = 'serviceusr'
SERVICE_PWD = 'servicepwd'
WSDL_URL = 'file:///folder/a.wsdl'
PROXY_NAME = 'proxy'
PROXY_PORT = 80
#----------------------------------------------------------

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

proxy_info = {'host': PROXY_NAME,'port': PROXY_PORT}
proxyHandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'https://(host)s:%(port)d/' % proxy_info})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxyHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
security = suds.wsse.Security()
token = suds.wsse.UsernameToken(SERVICE_USR, SERVICE_PWD)
security.tokens.append(token)
messageTransport = HttpAuthenticated(username = SERVICE_USR, password = SERVICE_PWD)
messageTransport.urlopner = opener
client = Client(url = WSDL_URL, location = SERVICE_URL, transport = messageTransport)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
result = client.service.ParseValidAddress('1 ABC Street Somwhere')
```

Once the script runs I get the following error:

```
Error details: <class 'urllib2.URLError'> <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not 
known>
```

So I ran curl to check all the networking bits are working as follows:

```
curl -x proxy:80 https://service1.com/1/soap
```

This returns  a SOAP message which indicates the network configuration and proxy are set-up correctly. So why does suds not do the same? Where have I failed?

Comment: Can you clarify what port your proxy is running on?

Comment: Proxy is on port 80. Which is strange for HTTPS right?

Comment: Are you sure your proxy host `proxy` is resolvable? Try adding the FQDN for the `proxy` host. In other words `PROXY_NAME = 'proxy.example.com'`. It is not strange that the proxy running on port 80 also is used or HTTPS. We have the same thing at work.

Comment: Did nslookup on proxy got back proxy IP address.

Comment: `proxyHandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'https://(host)s:%(port)d/' % proxy_info})` This doesn't look right, since your proxy is not answering on `443` but `80`. Your URL looks like `https://proxy:80/`, is that right?.

Comment: Success! I did the following and it worked. Added proxySettings = {'https':'http://{0}:{1}'.format(PROXY_NAME, PROXY_PORT)} and then set the option in the client client.set_options(proxy = proxySettings). Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! I did the following and it worked. Added `proxySettings = {'https':'http://{0}:{1}'.format(PROXY_NAME, PROXY_PORT)}` and then set the option in the client `client.set_options(proxy = proxySettings)`. Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 2):

should it be

```
proxyHandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'https://%(host)s:%(port)d/' % proxy_info})
```

(note the "s" at the end of both "https" and the "%").

Comment: Hi. Oh, yes that's right will edit now. Unfortunately still Errno-2. Thanks.